# How can I query data from multiple tables and sort by time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to show a user a feed which would combine two different types of posts, each with a different schema. It seems like a union won't work because they have different columns. I'm using postgres and sqlalchemy

I was thinking of fetching the entries from table1 and then the entries from table2, merging them, and then sorting by the date would be very inefficient.

EDIT:

I want to be able to query for a list of posts and images and have them sorted by `created_at`.

Posts table and Images table:

```
Post
    title
    body
    created_at
    ...many more


Image
    img_url
    caption
    created_at
    ...many more
```

Comment: Show your table definitions, some sample data and the expected output based on the example.

Comment: Added a concrete example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option:

```
SELECT created_at
FROM (
    SELECT created_at
    FROM Post
    UNION ALL
    SELECT created_at
    FROM Image
)
ORDER BY created_at
```

Note that this could also be done without a subquery, but I find it clearer this way and it makes it more convenient to add filters.

Technically the query above is in it's current form the same as:

```
SELECT created_at
FROM Post
UNION ALL
SELECT created_at
FROM Image
ORDER BY created_at
```

SQLAlchemy example:

```
q1 = sess.query(SomeClass).filter(SomeClass.foo=='bar')
q2 = sess.query(SomeClass).filter(SomeClass.bar=='foo')

q3 = q1.union_all(q2).order_by('created_at')
```

Concrete example with a common ancestor (using an inferred version of your models):

```
class FeedItem(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Post(FeedItem):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('feed_item.id'), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(100))
    body = Column(Text())
    created_at = Column(DateTime())


class Image(FeedItem):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('feed_item.id'), primary_key=True)
    img_url = Column(String(200))
    caption = Column(Text())
    created_at = Column(DateTime())

feed_items = with_polymorphic(FeedItem, [Post, Image])
query = session.query(feed_items).order_by('created_at')
```

Comment: That only selects the created_at times, I want to be able to fetch all the columns to display it to the user. Getting `ERROR:  each UNION query must have the same number of columns` when I change it to `SELECT *`

Comment: @kishinmanglani: that's true, you need to have the same columns in both. Note that you can "fake" columns like this: `SELECT ''::text AS some_column`

Comment: That's not a clean solution and would probably be difficult to do with SQLAlchemy. Is there no other alternative? I wish I could subclass both of these from a FeedItem parent class and query that

Comment: Besides changing your table structure to have common ancestor not really that much else you can do. SQLAlchemy supports this fairly easy though: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union Note that you should use `union_all` for performance reasons if you can :)

Comment: So I can have a common ancestor/parent class that would make this work? I can have a FeedItem parent class and have each of these inherit from that class? Then what would I do?

Comment: What you are looking for in that case is polymorphic inheritance which is a rather complex matter to do efficiently, but supported by sqlalchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#creating-joins-to-specific-subtypes

Comment: Or simpler, concrete table inheritance: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#concrete-table-inheritance

Comment: It's unclear to me–will that solve my problem? If I have them inherit from a FeedItem class with an id and created_at and then each table has very different columns, will I be able to query for them sorted by created_at with all the fields?

Comment: @kishinmanglani: I've added an example of how you can make it work

Comment: seems to be working really well so far. What would the performance on something like this be? Also, would it be necessary for me to add an item_type to the FeedItem column if I wanted to do some fancy filtering? Seemed like a good idea at first, but I figured if I wanted to do filtering I could query the individual table instead.

Comment: Well, the `with_polymorphic` generates a query with a `union all` in it so the basics should be pretty fast. In the end it will depend on the filters you will be doing but you should be fairly safe. As for an extra column, could help for performance but probably not needed, sqlalchemy will add a virtual type column for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75060/discussion-between-kishinmanglani-and-wolph).